# Angularjs How to push the new value for the scope object once it is used in the directives

Tags: angularjs

I want to push the new values for my main scope object through the directives.

please advise me how to do that.

In my sample I am using $scope.saveNew function for this but it is not working.

it throw the error "Error: $scope.users is undefined"

```
    myApp.directive("userName", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<td class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">Add New</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<input ng-model="newValue.name">' +
             '<input ng-model="newValue.phone">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="saveNew()">Save</a>' +
            ' or ' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
        '</div>' +
    '</td>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: function(element, attrs) {
          if(attrs.type=='add'){
            return editorTemplate;
          }
          else{
          return editorTemplate1;
          }
        },
        scope: {
            value: "=userName"
        },
    controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = {
            editableValue: $scope.value,
            editorEnabled: false
            };
            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
            };
             $scope.saveNew = function() {
                $scope.users.push({name:$scope.newValue.name,phone:$scope.newValue.phone});
                $scope.disableEditor();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$scope.users` was not defined.
Before pushing objects into it, you should initialize it outside `saveNew` function:

```
$scope.users = [];
```

Comment: it is already added in the controller

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
 
 $scope.users = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
     {name:'John', phone:'555-1278'},
                    {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}];
}]);

Comment: If you want access to a parent scope variable, you should pass it to the directive's scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an isolated scope through `scope: { .. }`. This means that your directive's scope wont' prototipically inherit from the parent scope. There are two fixes to this situation:

**First solution:**

If you think that your directive should be isolated, pass `users` to your directive as you do for `userName`.

**Second solution:**

If you wish to access the parent's scope `users` variable, set `scope` to `true`. However, be aware that every instance of your directive will share the same `users` object/array.